# PHP if $_GET isset and not equal to

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this condition, what I am trying to do is say, if $_GET['subpage'] is not equal to registerupcoming then do this, but I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: subpage in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/losanihomes/views/includes/header.php on line 26

So I tried the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['subpage']) && $_GET['subpage'] != 'registerupcoming'){

//Do Something

}
```

but the problem is, if subpage is not set, then it does not go into the condition, I only want to not go into this condition if subpage is not equal to registerupcoming

Answer (score 7):

Just change your `&&` to `||` and `isset()` to `!isset()`:

```
if(!isset($_GET['subpage']) || $_GET['subpage'] != 'registerupcoming'){

//Do Something

}
```

Now if that variable isn't set or has the wrong value you will redirect.